# How to disable a Button in ListView rows connected to ArrayAdapter?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

My class ProductAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
on getView i'm inflating rows with 2 buttons in the each row for (+) and (-)
and set anonim OnClickListener for each button , like this :

```
 viewHolder.removeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BigDecimal count = product.getCount().subtract(BigDecimal.ONE);
            if (count.signum() < 0) count = BigDecimal.ZERO;
            product.setCount(count);
            viewHolder.countView.setText(formatValue(count, product.getUnit()));
            mListener.onCardClick(v);
        }
    });
```

On activity i need to do some AsyncTask when i'm using integer value from each row.
The problem is when AsyncTask executing user still can change product adapter(Buttons are working). 
I need to disable them while AsyncTask is working and then reenable after completing.
I was trying to disable ListView with no luck.
Also i was trying to override ArrayAdapter methods isAllEnadled and isEnabled also with no luck.

Comment: How are buttons working during AsyncTask operation? Don't you show a progress dialog of some sort?

Comment: no i don't use any sort of dialog to user while process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem, you need a **State** and a place to save this, this **State** can be used to control the click behavior. You can save this either **in the product itself** or **some other place** like a list corresponding to that index

Something like

```
protected void onPreExecute(Void result) {
product.setFetching(true)
}


protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
product.setFetching(false)
}
```

in `onClick()` you can check same and return like this

```
if (product.isFetching())
return;
```

Comment: This means i need to store extra boolean value in each row like "lock". And set in true in aech row before process and false after? Any other way? Looks not good.

Comment: You need a state and a place to save this,  this state can be used to control the click behavior. You can save this either in the product itself or some other place like a list corresponding to that index.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a callback method for enable/disable buttons. You can use an interface for that.

pseudocode:

```
public interface ButtonsHandler {

    void enableButtons();
    void disableButtons();

}
```

Then you have to implement that interface in your viewHolder

```
public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements ButtonsHandler {
...
    void enableButtons() {
        yourButton1.setEnable(true);
        yourButton2.setEnable(true);
    }

    void disableButtons() () {
        yourButton1.setEnable(false);
        yourButton2.setEnable(false);
    }
...

}
```

Third, when you call the listener from the Holder to start the task, pass the object itself to manage buttons handling.

```
mListener.onCardClick(View v, ButtonsHandler buttonsHandler);
```

so the call will be:

```
mListener.onCardClick(v,viewHolder);
```

And finally, while your asynktask is working, you can call

```
buttonsHandler.disableButtons();

...

buttonsHandler.enableButtons();
```